List of tables and list of figures
I used the code below in my project but it brings out the list of tables and list of figures in block letters. Can someone help please. I only need the first letter in the list to be capitalized.
\newpage
{\tableofcontents}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Table of Contents}
\newpage
{\listoftables}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of Tables}
\newpage
{\listoffigures}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of Figures}


use \`not**` to mark a code section. the code you show does not change the case of any letters so any uppercasing is due to code you have not shown. Please always show a complete small test file that shows the problem.

Welcome. // After making your code compile, i.e. when we run it in our installations, please add a screenshot and/or a mock-up of current/intended version. Thank you

You generally should not do this by hand, especially if the lists are more that a page. See the tocbibind package. Please explain the comment about the block letters?

Please do tell us which document class you employ.
